# Xsane in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS; can't resize standard options window

Tags: window, xsane

Xsane generally works fine, but sometimes, it loses window sizes.

In the $HOME/.sane/xsane directory, there is a ".drc" file for the Xsane, and it does have things like:

```
"xsane-main-window-x-position"
1400
"xsane-main-window-y-position"
60
"xsane-main-window-width"
460
"xsane-main-window-height"
500
```

... for the main window.  However, there are no such settings for width of the standard options screen.  For some reason, my standard options screen is tiny, and I can't resize it.  It is just a small window, with a "."  Nor, can I maximize it (that option is grayed out).  I also tried inserting two lines to see if they weren't documented:

```
"xsane-standard-options-window-height"
400
"xsane-standard-options-window-width"
400
```

But no joy there. Any thoughts on how to solve this?

The window looks like this:

[image]

BTW, I did some poking around, and found there are command line options to change window sizes; xdotool, for example, but after getting the window ID and trying to change the window size... again, no joy.

Comment: I am having the [same issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/679321/resize-xsane-tiny-window-in-gnome) in Ubuntu 21.04 and 21.10 except for me it is the Advanced options window.  I have had no success yet.  Have you made any progress?